# EF Core ordering within groups themselves

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How to maintain order within groups created by `GroupBy` method? The `OrderBy` will order the groups but not elements in the groups.

For example:

```
_cptContext.Orders
           .GroupBy(x => x.NoOfItemsInOrder, x => x)
```

How to make sure that `Orders` are ordered by `Order.TotalPrice` within the group?

Comment: Did you try  .OrderBy(x => x.TotalPrice );  maybe also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747112/entity-framework-order-by-and-then-group-by   also GrouBy is spelled GroupBy. you are missing a p.

Comment: @BartMcEndree I think you missed the point of the question

Comment: I don't think you can do this, at least not without projecting the result into a new result, something like `.Select(x => new { NoOfItems = x.Key, Orders =  x.OrderBy(o => o.TotalPrice)})`, though you will likely have to enumerate the entire result first (e.g. with `ToList`)

Comment: What is the actual problem? Grouping in SQL *eliminates* all rows in a group and replaces them with a single row containing the key value and aggregates. There's no order inside a group. The operation `.GroupBy(x => x.NoOfItemsInOrder, x=>x)` is actually a LINQ-to-Objects operation that reshapes the query results on the client side. That `x` is an `IEnumerable<TSource>` which means you can use `x=>x.OrderBy(ord=>ord.TotalPrice).ToArray()`. This is similar to calling `.AsEnumerable()` before `GroupBy()` to load all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overload of Enumerable.Groupby that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3))))

Apparently, `_cptContext.Orders` is an `IQueryable<Order>`, where every `Order` has at least a property `NoOfItemsInOrder`.

It seems to me, that you want to make groups of Orders. Every group contains orders that have the same number of items. The Orders in the group need to be ordered by some value, for instance the order date.

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = ...

var ordersGroupedByNrOfItems = orders.GroupBy(

    // parameter keySelector: make groups with same value for property  NoOfItemsInOrder
    order => order.NoOfItemsInOrder,

    // parameter resultSelector, for every found NoOfItemsInOrder,
    // and all Orders that have this value for this property make one new:
    (noOfItemsInOrder, ordersThatHaveThisNoOfItemsInOrder) => new
    {
        // select only the properties that you plan to use, for instance:
        NoOfItemsInOrder = noOfItemsInOrder,

        Orders = ordersThatHaveThisNoOfItemsInOrder
            // order these Orders by Date
            .OrderBy(order => order.Date)

           // from every Order in the sorted sequence take 
           // only the the properties that you plan to use
           .Select(order => new
           {
               Id = order.Id,
               Total = order.Total
               Date = order.Date,
               ... // etc

               // not needed, you already know the value:
               // NoOfItems = order.noOfItemsInOrder,
           })
           .ToList(),
    });
```

The result is a (query for) a sequence of objects, where every object has two properties `NoOfItemsInOrder`, and `Orders`.

Orders is a List of objects, containing several properties of Orders that have the same value for `Order.NoOfItemsInOrder`. The list is ordered by increasing value for property `Order.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to project the result into a new object and do the ordering there. For example:

```
var orderedResults = _cptContext.Orders
    .GroupBy(x => x.NoIfItemsInOrder, x => x)
    .Select(x => new // You may want to use a custom class here
    {
        NoOfItems = x.Key, 
        Orders = x
            .OrderBy(o => o.TotalPrice)
            .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: You should put `ToList` before `GroupBy`, otherwise query will be ineffective.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I realise it wasn't actually needed and the ToList needs to be done inside the projection to do all the work in the DB

Comment: Which DB work do you expect here? SQL do not have analogue of grouping and returning grouping details. Only aggregations are supported.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The above query will run a `GROUP BY` in the database to get the `NoOfItemsInOrder` in a group

Comment: May I replace `Select` with `ToDictionaryAsync` with no punishment attached?

Comment: @Yoda Depends what you mean by punishment. It will no longer run an GROUP BY in the db, but performance may be no different. You could also just add `ToDictionary` on the end of the above: `.ToDictionary(x => x.NoOfItems, x = > x.Orders)`

Comment: @DavidG, execute on you project similar query and analyze SQL. You will find weird Eager Loading query, for sure if it is translated.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did, it executes something like `SELECT t.NoOfOrders, o.Id, o.Name... FROM (SELECT NoOfOrders FROM orders GROUP BY NoOrOfrders) AS t LEFT JOIN..... etc.`

Comment: So, your simple grouping query transformed to Eager Loading query, which is ineffective. I you need grouping details - execute grouping on the client side, it is performance advise. In any case for result you need all records from database.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The DB is optimised to do queries like this so it's almost certainly better to do the work there. Also, I presume OP is going to add a filter on the data being returned, unless this is for a reporting system, in which case it would be better to feed all the data into a reporting system